# Spacebar on Samsung Series 7 Chronos not working

Tags: keyboard

The spacebar on my Series 7 Chronos does not register half the time.  I'll be typing along and my words end up **lookinglikethis**.

After further investigation, I noticed the spacebar does not response when pressed at the edges.  Basically, the areas under the "C" key and the "M" key do not respond to a press

It's weird, the bar physically "clicks" down (like it should), but does not register.  No matter how hard I press, It won't register in that area.

I noticed some complaints online about a 'sticky' or 'loose' spacebar, but they didn't mention it not registering.

We took it back to the store we bought it at and they noticed the same problem on the floor model.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This isn't an appropriate question for SU in its current form ([faq]).  If you need help resolving the issue with fixing the problem consider an [edit] to ask a specific question.

Comment: If its new, and under warranty, the most sensible thing is to get samsung to fix it

Comment: Just picked up a new unit.  Problem does not seem to be an issue on this unit.

Answer (score 1):

My first machine returned with faults, ambient lite sensor and streaming (the spacebar was okay). The replacement had the space bar problem, Samsung affected repair through a third party and the replacement part was as the original, in that there is only one pressure sensor under the space bar, so the design error is still prevalent.

So despite Samsung's assurance this is a one in a million error. I now have had two in a row.

Comment: that is to say spacebar ok on original but not on replacement or on replaced keyboard hence wordsrun together

Comment: If you register your account @alan you'll be able to go back and edit your previous responses automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a design flaw (same issue on my unit), so probably Samsung won't fix it under warranty. [There's a youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRXr35mDyLM) showing a fix for that.